# How to dynamically generate docstrings in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, autocomplete, docstring, language-server-protocol

Is there a way to dynamically generate annotations/docstrings from object values in TypeScript?

I have a `translations.json` file that looks something like this:

```json
{
  "hello": { "en": "hello", "de": "hallo" },
  "bye": { "en": "bye", "de": "tschüss" }
}
```

And a `translate.ts` that looks like this:

```js
import type translations from './translations.json';

type TranslationKey = keyof typeof translations;

function translate(key: TranslationKey){
  // some translation code
}
```

With this I get all the keys of the JSON-Object as completion suggestions when I use the `translate()` frunction.

**Now my question is:** Is it possible to dynamically generate some kind of docstring from the values of the json properties?
So that the suggestion popup of my editor shows the values as additional information.

**Desired result in the Editor:**

```
translate('<cursor>
          ╭───────╮╭───────────────╮
          │bye   >├┤bye            │
          │hello  ││───────────────│
          ╰───────╯│TranslationKey │
                   │en: bye        │
                   │de: tschüss    │
                   ╰───────────────╯
```

Answer (score 0):

These JSON completion entries are generated by the vscode JSON completion provider, which cannot be configured to construct these items in a specific way. The only way to modify the completion output is to write an own completion provider (which is probably too much work for such simple outcome).